# Calling a servlet on page visit

Tags: html, servlets

I have an HTML page for instance, AdminPage.html, however I want to restrict users from visiting this page when they're not logged in. For this I'd want to use a servlet, but how can I load said servlet when browsing to AdminPage.html. In the past I have only used servlets to handle forms, could anyone get me on track? I'm not looking for a how-to check if a user is logged in rather how I can load a servlet that does this on visiting a page, as I can not simply link to a form action.

What I'd like to do:
Visit page -> Load servlet -> Check if user is logged in -> [yes] show content
                                                         -> [no] show 403

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the static HTML file. If you want a URL handled by a servlet then that is where your focus should be.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>exampleservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/AdminPage.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet then either outputs a 200 and the HTML or it outputs a 403 and the error page.